# What is Program_Accessor in MSTest Testing framework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mstest

I have tried googling for the answer but have been unable to find anything on this topic.

What is the Program_Accessor in unit tests created by Visual Studio ? Where can I learn more about its uses and how to use it?

I am primarily focusing on testing and especially unit testing in Visual Studio and C#. Where can I learn more about unit testing in Visual Studio ?

Even if I don't get a direct answer, I will be really grateful if anyone could point out resources where I can learn about it (books, web articles, etc ).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

When `MsTest` is attempting the test `private` members of a class, it generates files with an  `_Accessor` suffix.  These are called private accessors and allow the test to get a hook into calling a private member in the class you are testing.

[Here is some msdn help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184796%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on the subject.

Comment: Thanks. This gives me some clue about it.
Also, any idea where in the Test Project is it specified that which project it is testing ? 

Like, in other words, how can I say by looking at the code that what exactly the "Program_Accessor" is referring to ?

Comment: If you open up the Program_Accessor file, you should see from the using statements and namespace which file it is targeting.  Also, the name 'Program' is probably the class name that the accessor was built for.

Comment: The accessor file just contains the name of the project exe file that is produced in the /bin/Debug/ directory. I think that's what links it to the project being tested. It does not have any using statements. Just the name of the exe file and below it, it says "Desktop". Thanks for pointing it out. :) I still couldn't find the generated Accessor class though.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion one of the best books is "The art of Unit Testing" by Roy Osherove.

It is NOT focusing on testing in Visual Studio but it will give you an excellent understanding how to write good unit tests AND how to write testable code.